# Create a base view model, but can't seem to hook into it in OnActionExecuting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewdata

I create a baseviewmodel that my other strongly typed view models inherit from.

BaseController:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
            var baseViewModel = ViewData.Model as BaseViewModel;
            if (baseViewModel != null)
            {
                // set common properties that I want to use in all views
            }
}
```

Now when I set a breakpoint on the if cluase, it seems baseViewModel is always null.

How do I set the base ViewData.Model to be of BaseViewModel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OnActionExecuting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) is too early to look at the model.

> Called before the action method is invoked.

You can see model in OnActionExecuted.

Answer (score 2):

The `ViewData` is intended to send model from controller action to view.

Your `OnActionExecuting` hook is BEFORE the action method is invoked... so that is why you see the viewdata's model as null. Try using `OnActionExecuted` instead.

You can then check if the Model is of that base type using the keyword `is` this way:

```
if(ViewData.Model != null && ViewData.Model is BaseModel){

    var base = ViewData.Model as BaseModel;
    // set common properties
}
```